# Xcode why does my UISwitch not work after awhile?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiswitch

I am using a UISwitch in one of my tabbed applications.  The UISwitch is on the bottom of the screen.  When I first start the App, the switch works fine.  I can rotate from portrait to landscape, everything works fine.  I can even go to other tabs and come back and the switch still works in both landscape and portrait.  However, if I go back and forth between tabs maybe five times, the switch works in portrait, but not landscape .  Has anyone ever seen or heard of this?  Anyone know of a reason this could happen?  I have used

```
[infoSwitch setOn:NO];
```

in my viewWillAppear, so that the switch always starts OFF.  Is there something I am missing about using a switch?  I did the same things I have done in the past to get switches to work.  Any help will be much appreciated!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIView`s may be visible but will fail to get input if they're outside of the bounds of their parent view. So a first diagnostic would be to give the parent view some sort of obvious gaudy colour so that you can see its bounds visibly, then try your rotation and switching to see whether you can force an error there.

You can also set `clipsToBounds` to `YES` to ensure that views don't show subviews that are out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have a blue background on my view and it seems that the switch never goes outside of that.  I also have another view within the parent view, so I changed that so I could see it too.  It never overlaps the switch.  So I am pretty sure the switch is always in the parent view, and not covered by any other view.  What is the clipsToBounds that you are talking about, I never heard of it.  Thanks again!

Comment: `clipsToBounds` is a property on `UIView` with a default value of `NO`. If it's set to `YES` then children of that view are clipped to its bounds. The net effect is that things aren't drawn if you can't interact with them. It might be a good idea to do a quick recursive walk down from your controller's view and set that on all subviews, to see whether your switch eventually disappears.

Comment: thanks again, I have two things that I sunthesized in this view, a graph hosting view (I'm using core plot) and the switch.  I set clipsToBounds to YES for both.  But after I go from one view to the other three times, the problem shows itself.  My button never disappears though.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to add any other interactive elements, as a test? Like throw in a `UIButton` (it doesn't need to be connected to anything, since they animated regardless) next to the switch. That'll tell you whether it's a responder chain hiccup or whether the switch itself is somehow at fault.

Comment: Wow, the button stops working at the same time. And it always stops after the third time!  But I can see both of them at all times too.  And the graph hosting view never covers them up, or do they appear to be drawn outside the main view.

Comment: Another thing I tried was to make the graph hosting view really small, so it did not interfere with the switch and new button.  But still on the third time it stopped working.

Comment: Still on the responder chain guess, what happens if you move the button and/or switch right the way to the top left corner of the topmost view in your hierarchy?

Comment: if I move both the switch and button anywhere else, they either disappear or don't work.  They only work if they are outside of the graph hosting view, but within the view.  Any other ideas?  I would love to hear them.